# How can I measure the average values of GA custom variables?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-analytics

I'm intrigued by GA's _trackPageLoadTime method, because it logs into a table that shows average load time alongside other factors like pageviews, bounce rate, etc (see [sweet screenshot](http://d15h9h74b5uvt7.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/ga-site-speed-track-pages-loading.png)).

I want to take it further and do something similar super-simple JS perf — start tracking things like the time window.load calls, the delay before an image loads, the total execution time of an expensive page, etc.

So far, I'm tracking this info in Custom Vars and it all records fine — an example entry would be "Window Load","2.67" — but of course, GA treats them as discrete values, which is useless for actual perf.

Any suggestions? Is there a built-in GA way for viewing my data this way, a third-party method I could try....or would I need to program something through the API (maybe with the [Garb](https://github.com/vigetlabs/garb) Ruby gem) to extract these numbers and make some use out of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Analytics Events](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html). That's what you're looking for. You can set 3 string parameters and a fourth numeric value. Then you can see the total summed values or the average value.

One thing to notice is that it wont work with float, only integer numbers. So you may want to report milliseconds in that example that you gave.

Comment: Will test this tonight, but it sounds perfect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Using this concept to build an exception-catcher/mass perf tool that uses GA to track data. Thanks!